# Regular Expression for email formatting without hypen at first and last

Tags: regex, email-validation

I have created the regular expression which will take the email address as in following format:

```
abc@xyz.com.in
```

**Regular Expression**

`/^(?!-)[\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4}/`

I am trying to do the email which is not having hyphen at start and last.

**Invalid Format**

```
-abc@xyz.com
abc@xyz.com-
```

**valid format**

```
abc@xyz.com
abc@xyz.com.in
```

Comment: These ad-hoc email address regexes are basically always broken. You are breaking domain names with more than four characters in the TLD (except without a `$` anchor I suppose longer ones will slip through) and you are breaking plussed addresses.

Comment: How about something simple like e.g. [`^[^\s@-][^@\s]*@[^@\s]*[^\s@-]$`](https://regex101.com/r/9cf9Qb/1) This will prevent to start or end with `-` or `@` and ensure, `@` occurs only once.

Comment: Or like `^\w+(?:[.-]\w+)*@\w+(?:[.-]\w+)*\.[a-z]{2,4}$` https://regex101.com/r/HwoRhi/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `\w` to each end of your regex, and include the end anchor`$`

```
^\w[\w.-]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4}\w$
```

Note also the dot doesn't need escaping within a character class.

Comment: This will allow all kinds of characters instead of the dash, for example `@` which is not allowed.

Comment: @RoToRa how so? There is *one* `@` character. Where in the regex are "all kinds of characters" allowed?

Comment: `[^-]` matches all characters (except dash). I just used `@` used as an example. The whole regex, for example, matches `@abc@xyz.com`. Try it out: https://regex101.com/r/a69sgY/1

Answer (score 1):

Your regex can be edited in a simple way (see a demo at [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/UhpvdO/2)):

```
/^[\w\.]+[\w\.\-]*@[\w\.]+\.[\w\.]{2,4}$/
```

- `^`: This is the beginning of the line
- `[\w\.]+`: This is the first part of the email before `@` can have only word characters (`\w`) or dot (`\.`) at least once.
- `[\w\.\-]*`: After that, the same characters from the list before can occur including the dash (`\-`) and as many times as you want. Remember, the dash has to be escaped if used in the list between `[` and `]`, otherwise it represents a range instead of the dash itself.
- `@`: This matches itself.
- `[\w\.]+`: `After the` @` character, there must be at least one character from the list.
- `\.`: Then followed by the dot literally.
- `[\w\.]{2,4}`: Finally the last 2-4 characters.
- `$`: And the end of a line.

The difference between this and your Regex is just a little:

```
/^[\w\.]+[\w\.\-]*@[\w\.]+\.[\w\.]{2,4}$/
/^(?!-)[\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4}/
```

I rather avoided the negative look-ahead and specify (whitelist) the characters that can occur on the position, unless it is really needed to blacklist them (which I generally try to avoid). The rest of the Regex is quite similar except you should escape the dash `-` character between the list braces `[` and `]`.

Finally, I omitted the capturing groups `(` and `)` and leave it up to you to place them wherever you need.

Comment: Inside character classes (`[...]`) you don't need to escape `.` nor `-` (if it's the first or last character), so `[\w\.\-]` can be written as `[\w.-]`.

Answer (score -2):

a complete email RegEx

```
/^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/
```

Comment: Except this doesn't satisfy the requirement to limit where hyphens are allowed.